# Switching from Test::Unit to RSpec/FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I've got an example set up demonstrating Test::Unit's testing. I want to use RSpec and FactoryGirl in order to do the equivalent of this example. I seem to be having trouble accomplishing that, so any help would be appreciated!

Terminal

```
$ rails new lab
$ cd lab
$ rails g model foo bar:integer
$ open test/unit/foo_test.rb
```

Ruby

```
#insert into test/unit/foo_test.rb
test "example test" do
  assert_not_nil foos(:one).bar, "FooBar is Nil"
  assert_instance_of Fixnum, foos(:one).bar, "FooBar isn't a Fixnum"
  assert_equal 1, foos(:one).bar, "Foobar != 1"
end
```

Terminal

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake test
```

Output

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

.

Finished tests in 0.109820s, 9.1058 tests/s, 27.3174 assertions/s.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing? I don't see any errors or issues in this description.

Comment: In the example I made a model and a test w/o any added gems.
I'm wondering how to do the same test using RSpec for testing and Factory Girl instead of fixtures